# UITabController flip

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have TabBarController in my AppDelegate :

```
IBOutlet TabBarViewController *tab;
```

This is the main controller in my app.

and in one of the `viewcontroller` inside the tabs i want to add a UIButton that when the user press it all the tabcontroller will change to another uiviewcontroller with flip animation.

i tried to achive it with this method:

```
RadioMainVC *radioMainVC = [[RadioMainVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"RadioMainVC" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *radioNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:radioMainVC];

[UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:radioNav animated:NO];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.tabBarController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And the flip won't work,any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `pushViewController:animated:` is a method of `UINavigationController`, but `self.tabBarController` is probably a `UITabBarController`, so this can't work.

Comment: Why the `presentModalViewController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I haven't tested this code but it might do the trick:

```
[UIView transitionFromView: self.tabBarController.view
toView: radioNav.view
duration: 0.5
options: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
    window.rootViewController = radioNav;
}];
```